# How to have a dynamic value in an HTML comment in Jade?

Tags: pug

I want to programatically set the content of a comment. But this doesn't work:

```
p Hello
// = 'Generated at ' + date
```

It just outputs this:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<!-- = 'Generated at ' + date -->
```

How can I output a comment with something dynamic in it? I can't see anything in the docs about this.

Comment: Unfortunately for you in this case, Jade does not evaluate the comment's value.  You can hack around this by doing: `!='<!-- Generated at ' + date + '-->'`

Comment: you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately for you in this case, Jade does not evaluate the comment's value. You can hack around this by doing:

```
!='<!-- Generated at ' + date + '-->'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) seems to work in [block comments](https://pugjs.org/language/comments.html#block-comments):

```
- const date = new Date()

// Generated at #{date}

//
  Generated at #{date}
```

Output (using Pug 2.0.4):

```html
<!-- Generated at #{date}-->

<!--Generated at Sun Jan 24 2021 20:30:16 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)-->
```