# Programmatic HTML Comment using Node.JS Jade/Pug

Tags: node.js, pug

For layout.jade, with an Environment Variable "Variable = Development",

I am trying to get

```
  body
    // Environment: process.env.Environment || "'Environment' App Setting not found"
```

To generate as
`<!-- Environment: Development -->`

So far, it is generating as `Environment: process.env.Environment || "'Environment' App Setting not found"`

How do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you should set comment from node js side. Pug make not interpreting dynamic code in comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a dynamic value in an HTML comment in Jade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829920/how-to-have-a-dynamic-value-in-an-html-comment-in-jade)

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829920/how-to-have-a-dynamic-value-in-an-html-comment-in-jade):

```
body
    != "<!-- Environment: " + (process.env.Environment || "'Environment' App Setting not found") + " -->
```

To make it easier to read, you can also concatenate the comment with a variable that you would set on the previous line.

```
body
    - var envComment = process.env.Environment || "'Environment' App Setting not found"
    != "<!-- Environment: " + envComment + " -->"
```

However, I don't think `process.env` is normally accessible to Pug. You'd need to pass that variable to it from Node.js/Express as a variable. See the bottom of [this page](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) for info on passing that `process.env.Environment` variable.